# Traversing a subset of Graph for complex queries

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I'm fairly new to Gremlin and I'm trying to make a query more efficient.

With a graph that looks something like this:

```
[vertex: label=a] -> [vertex: label=b] -> [vertex: label=c] -> [vertex: label=d]
```

I need to traverse the graph, and get the results for each step of the traversal.

For example, from my base Vertex I may need to get everything related to it with the label "b" *and* everything related to "b" with the label "c" and so on.

I can do the requests individually like this:

```
results1 = g.V('someid').out().hasLabel('b').toList()
results2 = g.V('someid').out().hasLabel('b').out().hasLabel('c').toList()
results3 = g.V('someid').out().hasLabel('b').out().hasLabel('c').out().hasLabel('d').toList()
```

but that seems counter intuitive, and the response time starts to stack up.

I'm not really sure what I'm looking for, but maybe someway to continue searching a subset of the graph rather than starting from the base vertex every time.

EDIT:

I found the Union step, but this seems to combine multiple small queries into one big query and I believe ends up with the same inefficiencies as doing all the queries individually.

Comment: Trying to make sure I fully understand your question. Are you looking for a way to start a future traversal from places you have found before? If so you can pass a list of IDs to the `V()` step as one option.

Comment: Sorry if I was't super clear. When starting the query I have a single ID, which I pass to V(). I then need to recursively get relationships for that vertex. So I need V()->A and V()->A->B and V()->A->B->C etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get back the `path` of where your query went is quite straightforward in Gremlin. Here is a simple example using a data set that models airline routes:

```
g.V('3').  
  repeat(out().hasLabel('airport').simplePath()).
  until(has('code','AGR')).
  limit(5).
  path().
    by('code')

==>[AUS,JFK,BOM,AGR]
==>[AUS,YYZ,BOM,AGR]
==>[AUS,LHR,BOM,AGR]
==>[AUS,FRA,BOM,AGR]
==>[AUS,EWR,BOM,AGR]
```

You will find some related examples here:
http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html
http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.pdf

Comment: Thanks Kelvin, `path` was exactly what I was looking for. I just need to do some work grouping the results now. By the way, I was using your book to pick up Gremlin before you even answered my question! It's an excellent resource, I guess I'm not an excellent reader as I missed this bit!